# Convert snippet Jquery to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, code-snippets

any help I can get to convert this Jquery snippet to JS vanilla? I've been trying to do it but always get error. Thanks in advance for any reply.

Edit: function move_player is what I am trying to translate, the rest is already done.

````
$(document).ready(function() {
  var end_of_track = 15;
  var players = [
    {
      id: 1,
      position: 0,
      keycode: 80,
      css_locator: '#player1_strip',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      position: 0,
      keycode: 81,
      css_locator: '#player2_strip',
    },
  ];

  function advancePlayer(keyCode) {
    players.forEach(function(player) {
      if (
        keyCode == player.keycode &&
        players[0].position < end_of_track &&
        players[1].position < end_of_track
      ) {
        move_player(player.css_locator);
        player.position++;
        winner(player.position, player.id);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    advancePlayer(e.keyCode);
  });
});

function move_player(strip) {
  $(strip)
    .find('td.active')
    .removeClass('active')
    .next()
    .addClass('active');
}

function winner(player, num) {
  if (player > 14) {
    alert('Player ' + num + ' has won!');
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Please show your attempt so that we can help you debug it. Also, what is the value of `strip`? It's important so that we know if we're dealing with a single element, or a collection.

Comment: I'm trying to translate jQuery code to vanilla js.. I will send the rest of the code so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ES6 is allowed, you could use the `querySelector` to find the current active `td` element and then remove its active class from the elements `classList` then use `nextElementSibling` to get its sibling `td` element and add the the `active` class to it.

ES6:

```
function move_player(strip)
{
    var activeElement = document.querySelector(`${strip} td.active`);
    activeElement.classList.remove('active');

    var nextElement = activeElement.nextElementSibling;
    nextElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8bLt1hep/)

Before ES6:

```
function move_player(strip)
{
    strip = strip.replace('#', '');
    var stripElement = document.getElementById(strip);
    var activeElements = stripElement.getElementsByClassName('active');

    if(activeElements.length > 0)
    {
        var active = activeElements[0]
        active.classList.remove('active');
        var nextElement = active.nextElementSibling;
        nextElement.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8bLt1hep/2/)

Comment: I tried this earlier, didn't work. The error I get is this TypeError: strip.querySelector is not a function

Comment: querySelector is ES6. I've updated it for earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks but still getting error.. This time it says strip is null

Comment: Sorry didn't see you were trying to pass a selector instead of an element to `move_player` try the updated

Comment: No problem :) If this answer helped please consider upvoting or selecting it as the question solution